# Python declare object functions at Init

Tags: python

Suppose I have a Class that's passed a set of options.

For example:

```
class Thing(object): 
    def __init__(self, options): 
        self.name = options['name']
        if options['material'] == 'organic': 
            self.living = options['living'] 
            if self.living: 
                self.kingdom = options['kingdom'] 
        else:
            self.material = options['material']
```

So if it's material and organic, it will have an additional option specifying if it's living, if it's living it will also have a kingdom etc.

Suppose I want to define a function in `class Thing` that will for example:

```
def belongToKingdom(self): 
    print self.kingdom
```

But I only want such a function defined at `__init__` if kingdom is passed in options, otherwise ignored. What's the correct way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Have a subclass `class LivingThing(Thing):`?

Comment: Yeah I know, it was just supposed to be a simplified example, the actual use case is a little different because there is a set of functions that's dynamically generated from an array of paired values. So I can't just make subclasses for every possible combination of pairs, I actually need to take a standard prototype function and generate it with a few variables determined by the value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, **options):
        if options.get('living',None):
            def belongToKingdom(self):
                print(self.kingdom)
            self.kingdom = options['kingdom']
            self.belongToKingdom = belongToKingdom
```

Comment: This might be appropriate for a different question, but suppose I don't know what the function I want to define will be called is there a way to str format the function name? I.e. a working equivalent for self.belongTo{0}.format(options['kingdom'])  <which would persumably always return True but anyways>

Comment: @user3467349 I can't really make sense of what you're asking, but it sounds like you're trying to put meaningful data in variable names. Don't do that! Just build a list of options instead, so `Thing().options` returns `{'living':True, 'kingdom':"Animal", ... }` and test for it

Comment: @user3467349 but of course, there is in fact a way to do just what you want. Instead of manipulating `self`, manipulate `self.__dict__`. Then you can use a string instead of a variable name. For example: `self.__dict__["belongTo{}".format('kingdom')] = lambda self: print(self.kingdom)` works (it's just uglier than sin)

Comment: Yes I was just thinking of that. I could also just make a new dictionary right i.e. self.printMyAttribute = {} and then add into it so it looks like {'kingdom': <function kingdom> } etc. Is there a reason you would discourage something like that?

Comment: @AdamSmith this won't work; `belongToKingdom` is a function, which isn't quite the same as a method. You need to [`from types import MethodType`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.MethodType) then make the assignment `self.belongToKingdom = MethodType(belongToKingdom, self)`

Comment: Declaring as self.belongToKingdom = makes it uncallable outside of the class, because it expects to get self as an argument. So it's not a good solution. Edit: declaring without self as an argument seems to work though.